# How to enable special characters in Drupal Menu?

Tags: navigation, 5

I am using Drupal5 and Nice Menu Module. I need to provide a URL in my Menu dropdown. There are special characters in it. When I add the complete path it works but on giving the relative path special characters doesn't show up(it gets replaced by the hex code).  How can I display the special characters in Drupal Menu Dropdown as it is?

Comment: I guess that you can review in the `nice_menus.module` file, specifically in `theme_nice_menu_tree()` module function to parse/filter/encode/replace each hexadecimal string that seems be pushed by `menu_item_link($mid)` or `$mid` string. remember do this kind of test with a copy of your production site. I have not tried this suggestions, sorry, I only guess after a rough review of the code. I think that could be useful.

Comment: This is most likely working as designed - many special characters are not legal in URLs, and must be encoded.  If you post the specific characters that are causing trouble, a more detailed answer may be possible.

Answer (score 0):

I guess that you can review in the `nice_menus.module` file, specifically in `theme_nice_menu_tree()` module function to parse/filter/encode/replace each hexadecimal string that seems be pushed by `menu_item_link($mid)` or `$mid` string. Remember do this kind of test with a copy of your production site. I have not tried this suggestions, sorry, I only guess after a rough review of the code. I think that could be useful. - [@cigotete](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/12466/how-to-enable-special-characters-in-drupal-menu#comment12016_12466)